# C# Math.Round() on periodic doubles

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I've been looking for a while now and couldn't find a fitting answer to my question.
Might be a very small maths issue but I don't know.

Let's take the following code:

```
// simple double for simplicity
Double t = 1.33333333333;
// Rounding
Math.Round(t, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
Math.Round(t, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

Both result in 1.33. Because, why shouldn't they. That's how these roundings work. 1.66666 perfectly rounds to 1.67 of course.

But it doesn't fit my needs in this case.
I need the double to be rounded to two decimals but the last digit always rounded up to the next number.
Example:

```
// The following code can not be executed...
Math.CustomRounding(t, 2, WhateverFitsMyNeeds.ToNextEven);
```

The output in that case should be *1.34*. Rounding 1.11111 should result in 1.12. 1.222222 should round to 1.23 and so on...
Is there any way to accomplish that using C# or do I have to check for a 3 at the end and exchange it with a 4? Like with String formatting?

Comment: You are trying to get rounding wrong.  Add 0.005, then round.

Comment: You could multiply by 100, find the ceiling and then divide by 100.

Comment: @Salixalba's method is more appropriate because you can encapsulate it into a function where you give it a double and n to use 10^n for more granularity of what you want to round with ceiling.

Comment: What is "periodic doubles?"  And why do you want to round that strange way?

Comment: The system rounds that strange way. No way to change that. If I don't round that way too, we get a small delta in our reports. E.g. costs/hour = 140$. Working for 10min results in 23.3333 (periodic, therefore periodic rounding (non-native english speaker here...)) and needs to be rounded to 23.34. That's basically why. I'll try both solutions and give feedback according to performance as I'm populating a bunch of tables with a hell lot of data. Thanks so far! Once I'm good with a solution I'll give you feedback that you can post an answer for me to accept.

Comment: Sorry guys! Better late than never! I'm going with @HansPassant 's solution. Adding 0.005 is the best way in my case. Thank you!